# Laravel eloquent all() retrieval method not returning data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to fetch all records from a database table using `Post::all()` . Strangely, it's giving me a 500 error.

if I use a where clause like `Post::where('id', 1)->get()`, it works just fine. I checked the error log, but there's nothing there

Comment: Are you sure the issue is in `Posts::all()`? May you give some context please

Comment: Have you checked both your server log and laravel.log?

Comment: @JarmoT It's a memory limit problem, as per the server log. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like by running `Foo::all()` or `Foo::get()` you might be running into memory limit problems by sounds of it.
It is not advice to fetch all records from the table unless the table is controlled and contains only few records

You can always redefine the query after/before you have ran `all` or `get` functions

An `all()` call will return a collection where you can preform filtering after you collected the data
and `get()` will require you to specify filtering before execution as its done on SQL level.

Example:

```php
$exampleOne = Foo::where('bar', 1)->get(); //query builder
$exampleTwo = Foo::all()->where('bar', 1); //Laravel collection
```

Answer (score -5):

When you want to get all the data from a model, you have to use get() function:

```
Posts::get();
```

Answer (score -6):

if you want to get all the data, and get error on this code
`Posts::all()`

you can use get function:

`Posts::get();`

`DB::table('posts')->get();`

you can write command in terminal

`php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: `::all()` should works fine. Issue could be because of exceeding memory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).